# Apache: Request Entity Too Large

Tags: php, apache, vagrant, centos7

I'm working on a laravel project and file uploading is working correctly on smaller files but when I tried to upload a 400+ Meg file of sample data which is a text file I get

```
Request Entity Too Large

The requested resource
/table/create/import
does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data
provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit.
```

I have checked my php.ini file and tried setting the following per instructions I have found

```
upload_max_filesize = 5000M
post_max_size = 10000M
max_input_time = 300
max_execution_time = 500
```

I also have tried to set LimitRequestBody in the httpd.conf file on the folder where the files get uploaded to.

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/project-css/storage/app/flatfiles">
    LimitRequestBody 0 
</Directory>
```

I'm running this in a vagrant setup with centos. I have been looking into this for a few days now and I haven't found a answer. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: have you checked the applied values of your changed php.ini settings in a php file?

Comment: yes I checked they were applied by looking at the phpinfo

Comment: are you using mod_php or php-fpm? Either way it could be a memory issue.

Comment: yea i'm not running either mod_php or php-fpm. I did increase the memory limit in the php.ini to memory_limit = 1024M but still no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered the problem was with mod_security in the mod_security.conf I was able to increase the size SecRequestBodyLimit to be able to upload the file.